# Internet through different wifi does not work after sleep happens after Upgrade to 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04, network-manager, internet, suspend

Recently, I upgraded to 18.04 from 16.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad P50. When I come home, and wake up laptop from sleep, it connects to wifi connection but internet connectivity is not established. I can ping to router but cannot ping to any website. I restarted network-manager service but it does not wor.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading, by default network manager was not managing eth0 and wlan0 interfaces defined in

> /etc/network/interfaces

To enable network manager to manage these interfaces, open

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

change

*[ifupdown]
managed=false*

To

[ifupdown] 
managed=true

It solved the problem.