# Cannot Connect to Internet after first Disconnect

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, connection, wired

I have been running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad T580 for the last ~3 months with no issues. Installed an update a few days ago, rebooted, and started having very odd issues for both wired and wireless connections.

I boot up the laptop and it connects to my home network successfully and I can access the internet. I disconnect from the network (close the lid or just turn off the connection) then reconnect. I am still on my home network and can see other devices, but no request resolves when I try to browse the internet, except if I go to [www.google.com](https://www.google.com), that works! The only way to get back to normal is to reboot the laptop again.

Things I've tried:

- Pinging a well known IP address (8.8.8.8) to prove it is not a DNS issue, this fails.
- Run a service network-manager restart. This does not seem to have an effect.
- As above, I tested this on both wired and wireless and the same behavior occurs.
- I also tested this on my wireless hotspot which also behaved the same.
- Per other answers, looked at the dmsg logs and didn't see much.
- Tried [Internet through different wifi does not work after sleep happens after Upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071013/internet-through-different-wifi-does-not-work-after-sleep-happens-after-upgrade) , did not seem to help either.

Here is my wireless info, but the problem feels more like a general network configuration.

```
~$ sudo lshw -class network
   *-network             
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlp4s0
   version: 78
   serial: 04:d3:b0:7a:96:d0
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-43-generic firmware=34.0.1 ip=192.168.1.147 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:147 memory:ec000000-ec001fff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 21
   serial: 48:2a:e3:0f:9b:41
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.1-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:145 memory:ec100000-ec11ffff
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. A few days prior to the issues, I had configured a VPN using OpenVpn. I realized I had only been using it interactively through the terminal, but when I rebooted my laptop, it ran in the background as a daemon. The first time I disconnected, it never recovered and I was left in the state that I described.

I just turned the autoconnect in init.d to false, restarted, and everything works now.